# Making HTML page by fetching values from two Dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am creating a report for my project ( IP addresses that have made 'n' API calls). 
I want to create a table having attributes-3 columns (ip , url and count ) . 
Means this {ip}  has called this {url} by this {count}times.

So I have my information in two dictionaries ,

1. ip_count_dict formate : Number of unique ip that has been called

   ```
      { '127.32.4.5' : 3,
         '43.43.5.3' : 4
       }
   ```
2. ip_url_list_dict formate :Number of unique ip that has called url

   ```
      { '127.32.4.5' : '/v1/draft',
         '43.43.5.3' : '/v0/ready'
       }
   ```

Html Body :

```
    def get_email_html_body(ip_count_dict, ip_url_list_dict, start_timestamp, end_timestamp, count): 
        email_body = """
                <html>
                <head>
                  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                  <title>html title</title>
                  <h4 align= "center" >Summary : Platform Daily Status Report</h4>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <h4 align="center"> Start Timestamp : %s] - End Timestamp : %s] </h4> 
                    <table align= "center" border= "1px solid">
                        <thead >
                          <tr bgcolor="silver">
                            <th>Client Ip</th>
                            <th>URL</th>
                            <th>Count</th> 
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody> """

        res_html2  =  ""         
        for key, value in ip_url_list_dict.items():                    
            html2 = ("""         
                          <tr border = 1px black> 
                            <th>%s</th>
                            <td>%s </td>
                             </tr>"""  )% (key , value  ) 
            res_html2 = html2 +  res_html2

        html4 = """      
                     </tbody> 
                      </table>  
                      <table>
                </body>
                </html> """

        return email_body +  res_html2 + res_html3 + html4
```

I have a table having ip and url and its working but not able to add count in the same table . 
Do you give any logic to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
html2 = ("""<tr border = 1px black> 
              <th>%s</th>
              <td>%s</td>
              <td>%s</td>"""  )% (key, value, ip_count_dict.get(key, 0))
```

Comment: @Arya: I don't understand the question.  I am assuming that what you are getting as output currently is working, and my update would just be a replacement for your current line.

Comment: Though it does seem strange that the html2 assignment doesn't end with an ending `</tr>`.

Comment: I need to iterate two dicts at the same time  to make a table having ip address , url and number of times that url is called by client_ip.